# How to load a Bootstrap modal after successful submission of form and information retrieval?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a website built using HTML, CSS, PHP, and JavaScript. There is a section which displays a form and lets the user enter some information. On clicking the submit button, I wish to trigger a PHP file which contains the code for retrieving rows from database with the information supplied in the form. After that, I want to display the retrieved information in a Bootstrap modal or any other kind of popup and return to the home page.

When I put the data toggle and data target in the button tag and set the action of the form as the PHP file, it goes to the PHP code, retrieves the information, and doesn't display the modal, because the page gets refreshed.

Comment: please include what have you tried to solve this problem

Comment: you should use `ajax` for that.

Comment: Submit button can't use JS code(for showing the modal window) in case of success or fail, you need to create some `$.ajax` or `$.post` and do what you want.

Comment: after submit you can redirect to the page you want with session
and if there are a session you can active your  modal, if there isn't a session you don't display your  modal, you can read more in https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php